# Column names tolower() recursively (in list of dataframes)

Tags: r, list, recursion, lapply

This should be obvious, but I still haven't got my mind around `lapply` and its kin, and I haven't found a clear and simple answer to this on SO or Google. So with apologies for noobness, here goes:

I have a list with multiple embeddings, a bit like this (nabbing a reproducible example from [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/renaming-data-frame-columns-in-lists/)):

```
lst <- structure(list(Df1 = structure(list(Df1 = structure(list(Date = structure(c(14611, 14612), class = "Date"), Ta_200 = c(10.0067787761421, 5.9095282339839 )), .Names = c("Date", "Ta_200"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), Df2 = structure(list(Date = structure(c(14611, 14612), class = "Date"), rH_200 = c(64.9115310510325, 90.8615907551521)), .Names = c("Date", "rH_200"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Df1", "Df2")), Df2 = structure(list(Df1 = structure(list(Date = structure(c(14642, 14643), class = "Date"), Ta_200 = c(9.91976687351846, 8.79129183854663 )), .Names = c("Date", "Ta_200"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), Df2 = structure(list(Date = structure(c(14642, 14643), class = "Date"), rH_200 = c(76.9297879127307, 75.8021788747459)), .Names = c("Date", "rH_200"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Df1", "Df2"))), .Names = c("Df1", "Df2"))
```

The goal: make all column names at all levels lowercase using `tolower()`, for recursive lists of 2 or 3 levels deep (like here). I can loop through list elements but I'm trying to follow the recommendations I see everywhere to avoid for loops and use things from the `apply` family and from `dplyr`.

I can use `lapply` for the second level down like this:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) { names(x) <- tolower(names(x)) } )
```

But: (1) I don't understand how to do this recursively for the 1st and 2nd (and 3rd) levels, and (2) I'm kind of missing how to actually write the new lowercase names to the list items (the line above only returns them).

Comment: `setNames` is helpful: `lapply(lst, function(x) { setNames(x, tolower(names(x))) } )` That only does one level at a time, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function that calls itself recursively will do the trick, given that
you have no objection against all names at all levels being returned to
lower-case...

```
all_to_lower <- function(x) {
    ##  Update the name at the desired level, when present.
    if (! is.null(names(x)))
        names(x) <- tolower(names(x))
    ##  Decide if an iterative step should be used.
    if (is.list(x) & ! is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- lapply(
            X = x,
            FUN = all_to_lower)
    ##  Return to workflow.
    x
}

all_to_lower(lst)
$df1
$df1$df1
        date    ta_200
1 2010-01-02 10.006779
2 2010-01-03  5.909528

$df1$df2
        date   rh_200
1 2010-01-02 64.91153
2 2010-01-03 90.86159


$df2
$df2$df1
        date   ta_200
1 2010-02-02 9.919767
2 2010-02-03 8.791292

$df2$df2
        date   rh_200
1 2010-02-02 76.92979
2 2010-02-03 75.80218
```

**Edit:** It's of course possible to tweak the function so only the names of the data-frames are affected.  Simply replace `(! is.null(names(x)))` with `(! is.null(names(x)) & is.data.frame(x))`.

Comment: Lovely. I suppose this is what `rapply` (as 'recursive apply') is meant to be able to do but I couldn't get that to work, whereas your solution is elegant, generalises well, and works for my data.

Comment: I tried `rapply` too, and was a bit confused at first to why it didn't work.  But, as commented in the answer from @alistaire, `rapply` runs into problems here because a `data.frame` also is a `list`, and then it "walks down" one step more than we want it to do.  For other data-types I think `rapply` should work as we expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution for a two-level problem. It is a bit dense

```
# double lapply with as.data.frame wrapping second lapply
noCapsData <- lapply(lst, function(level2) lapply(level2, 
                  function(dfnames) setNames(dfnames, tolower(names(dfnames)))))
```

This routine checks for character vectors, which may be useful if you have more than one data type in your data.frames.

Comment: That returns something different when called upon `lst` as supplied in the example.

Comment: @alistaire Sorry. I read the title and wrote something to change the contents of the data.frames. But in the body the OP is asking about names of variables. I'll make the change.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have edited the title to reflect the question and its answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `lapply`s of `setNames`, depending on how many layers deep your list is. If all the data.frames are on a single level, you can get away with something like

```
lapply(lst, function(x){lapply(x, function(y){setNames(y, tolower(names(y)))})})
```

If you have data.frames on different levels, you may need to check whether the items you're iterating over are data.frames:

```
lapply(lst, function(x){if(is.data.frame(x)){
    setNames(x, tolower(names(x)))
    } else {
    lapply(x, function(y){if(is.data.frame(y)){
        setNames(y, tolower(names(y)))
    }})
}})
```

If your list goes deeper, iterate again.

There does exist `rapply`, a recursive version of `lapply`, but getting it to work properly on data.frames is a pain due to the fact that data.frames are lists.

Comment: Indeed, I initially thought `rapply` would be what I need, and while that may be true I couldn't get it to work. I have accepted the most general solution, which is the recursive function by @lars-arne-jordanger.